# Solve $f(x) = x^n$ for $n$ given the value of the definite integral of $f(x)$ between some values $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, logarithms

I have a curve $f(x) = x^n$, where $n$ is variable. The curve will be plotted from the $f(a)$ to $f(b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, and $b > a$. I want to find $n$ given the desired `area` under the curve.

Here's what I have so far:
$f(x) = x^n$
$$\int F(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

The definite integral of $F(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ is:
$$area = \frac{b^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Simplify by multiplying all terms by $(n+1)$:
$$area(n+1) = b^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$$

And this is the bit that I'm stuck at. I know that I want to solve for $n$, so I need to get it out of the exponents on the right hand side. This means that I need to take the log of all terms... but I'm stuck on exactly how to do that.

Can somebody walk me through solving for $n$, and try to explain why the steps that they take work?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think a closed form for $n$ exists in terms of $a$, $b$, and the area.

Comment: @Zhoe thanks for the edit, that makes it much more readable

Comment: @Potato can you elaborate on the idea of "a closed form"? I'm not sure that I'm familiar with that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that you plot the area as function of "n" for various discrete values. You then should locate two values of "n" which bracket the solution (I assume that "n" is not an integer). Then, now, you have to polish your solution. For that, Newton method is very simple. Starting with a guess (say n_old), you iterate according to
n_new = n_old - f[n_old] / f'[n_old]
Let me take an example with a=1, b=2 and an area equal to Pi. Plotting the function shows that the solution for "n" is between 2 and 3. Then, let us start with n_old = 2; the successive iterates will then be 2.75495, 2.63817, 2.63431, 2.63430 and so on. For n=2.6343, the computed area is 3.14159.

Comment: I like this method, but my end game is to turn this into an algorithm. Is there some way that I can estimate the value of n_old without plotting and visually inspecting the graph? Will Newton Method find a solution regardless of the starting value of n_old? Or will it get stuck in some local maxima or minima along the way?

Comment: @MusikPolice. You make a loop around "n" say from 0 to 1000 by steps of 1 and you exit the loop when the function changed sign. The initial guess is important; you can get to local minima's but not for the problem you posted. Please, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: Forgive me, but when I'm evaluating f(n_old) and f'(n_old), what value am I to use for x? if f(x) = x^n, I only know our estimate for n. The method doesn't seem to tell me what x is.

Comment: @MusikPolice. There is no "x" anywhere. Your equation ia area = .... which just involves "a", "b" and "n". "a" and "b" being known and the ares too, the only variable is "n" for which you have to solve. I do not see any place where I wrote "x" (but, since I am almost blind, it is always possible). Let me know if everything is OK or not.

Comment: The only equation to solve is is $$g(n) = -area + \frac{b^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$$. Replace f() by g() in my previous comments.